# ブラウザ上でテスト的な POST リクエストを実行したい

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http, firefox

今開発中のウェブアプリにおいて、API ではない、ブラウザ上のページ遷移の一貫で(他サイトから) POST リクエストが送られてくるので、それを受け取って、かつ画面表示するようなページを作成しようとしています。この機能のために、 POST リクエストを再現したいと思っているのですが、ふとどうやるか分からないので質問です。

## 質問

ブラウザ(firefox か chrome)に、 POST リクエストでのページ遷移を行わせることができるツールや機能などはありますか? POST なので、 url と `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` としてエンコードされるフォームデータを入力して、ブラウザ上に実際に POST でそのページを見にいくようなことがやりたいと思っています。

Comment: RESTとかAPIでの方法の解説ですが、応用すれば何か出来るのでは？[RESTful API のパラメータを変えての実行にも DevTools が便利でした](https://kuma-emon.com/it/pc/2095/), [「Advanced REST client」の使い方まとめ　～GoogleChromeの拡張ツール](https://viral-community.com/webservice/advanced-rest-client-8235/), [curlとAdvanced REST clientでAPIの動作確認する](https://qiita.com/aoyagikouhei/items/ea0007b1c4c8c6ba3017), [【Web API】Talend API Testerを使ってみた](https://www.isoroot.jp/blog/4241/), [【Chrome】ブラウザから簡単にREST APIを叩く方法【Talend API Tester（旧 Restlet Client）】](https://katblog.manadream.net/index.php/2019/02/11/rest-api-from-restlet-client/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

専用の機能は無さそうですが、コンソールでは可能です。以下、あたり前の話な気もしますが、長めのコードをコンソールに貼り付ける発想が無い方も居そうなので、一応回答とします。

- 遷移元のページ（Referer などを気にしないならどこでもよい）を開く
- 開発者ツールのコンソールを開く
- フォームの作成や [`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) / [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)を行なうコードを貼り付けて実行

コード例 1（スタック・オーバーフローの検索ページに Post で遷移）:

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <form id="TEST_FORM" action="https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="テスト" />
    </form>
`)
document.getElementById("TEST_FORM").submit()
```

コード例 2（上とほぼ同じで、要素の挿入まで）:

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <form id="TEST_FORM" action="https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="テスト" />
        <button type="submit">送信</button>
    </form>
`)
```

これは普通にブラウザ上のフォームを操作する必要が有ります。遷移元ページの構造やスタイルによりますが、だいたい末尾にフォームが表われるはずです。

Answer (score 0):

いまいち質問のコンテキストが読み取れず…

- [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/ja/documentation/webdriver/)
- [Power Automate Desktop](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/ja-jp/robotic-process-automation/)

みたいなものを求めているのでしょうか？ 違っていたら、何を必要としているのかを明確にしてください。